# HTTP used in location header instead of HTTPS

Tags: apache, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, mailman

**Setup:**

Nginx as reverse proxy, terminates https

Apache at localhost:8080 delivers Mailman application (admin gui) to Nginx

When I enter the exact URL in the browser like
https://lists.staging.xxx.de/mailman/ it works perfectly.

When I enter either https://lists.staging.xxx.de/mailman (without trailing slash) or even only https://lists.staging.xxx.de/ an Apache RedirectMatch kicks in, and sends back the correct url via header location info - **but with incorrect scheme**, that is "Location: http://lists.staging.xxx.de/mailman/"

When I do a `curl -L -v -s -o /dev/null localhost:8080` I get back: `Location: http://localhost:8080/mailman/`.

So I conclude:
Nginx correctly rewrites the host, but not the scheme.

So, either I have to change the configuration of Nginx, so it rewrites the header (ie scheme), or I have to make Apache aware, that - even https is terminated - header location statement should include a https.

Any help is appreciated!

Nginx config:

```
server {
listen xxx:443;

server_name lists.staging.xxx.de;

if ($host != lists.staging.xxx.de) {
       rewrite (.*) https://lists.staging.xxx.de$1 permanent;
} 

ssl on;
ssl_certificate  /srv/s-bliss/deployment/work/nginxmailman/lists.staging.xxx.de.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /srv/s-bliss/deployment/work/nginxmailman/lists.staging.xxx.de.key;

location / {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect          off;
}
```

}

Apache config:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName lists.staging.xxx.de

    Alias /mailman/icons /usr/lib/mailman/icons
    <Directory "/usr/lib/mailman/icons/">
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /mailman/archives /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
    <Directory "/var/lib/mailman/archives/public/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
            AddDefaultCharset off
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RedirectMatch ^/$ /mailman/
    RedirectMatch ^/mailman$ /mailman/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mailman/(archives|icons)
    RewriteRule ^/mailman/(.*) /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/$1 [H=cgi-script]
    <Directory "/usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI
            DirectoryIndex listinfo
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: You could try adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`. But that would require Apache to use it when constructing the response.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for the input - but how would I make Apache use that information?   Something like this?   `SetEnvIf HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "^https$" HTTPS=on
  SetEnvIf HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "^http$" HTTPS=off`

Answer (score 0):

Our provider came up with following solution:

```
http://lists.staging.xxx.de/mailman/ https://lists.staging.xxx.de/mailman/;
```

It works!

Update:
The header is now delivered correctly, but the payload (body) still contains a link to the http version.